# Calling Facebook app to take a picture

Tags: android, facebook, camera

I would like my app to do the following:
When I press a button, the installed Facebook app should be "called" with the intention to take a picture and post it on the Facebook profile.

I know there is a way to accomplish that in iOS, but is it also possible in Android?

**In Short:**
Press button --> Camera is started; after the picture is taken --> post the photo on facebook (after username and password input, *without* using the Facebook SDK)

Answer (score 1):

This is the `Activity` that gets launched when you press the photo icon in the Facebook app:

```
com.facebook.photos.taggablemediapicker.TaggableMediaPickerActivity
```

You can try starting that `Activity` via an `Intent`. The user will have to go through the flow of posting the picture.

You can also create an `Intent` and use `Intent.ACTION.SEND`, but the user will still have to finish the posting flow.